# jQuery ui drag children not parent

Tags: jquery, draggable

I have simple hierarchy of list items like

```
<ul>
    <li>Personal Details
        <ul style="position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px;" class="ui-draggable">     
            <li>First Name</li>
        <li>Last Name</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Employment Details
         <ul style="position: relative;" class="ui-draggable">
             <li>Title</li>
             <li>Department</li>
         </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/grimmus/PtzF4/1/

I want to only permit the child list items to be draggable. So, you cannot drag personal details but you can drag first name, last name etc.

I tried using children() before draggable but it pulls over all the children and not just one :-)

Does anyone know how i can achieve this ? Please check the fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/grimmus/PtzF4/1/

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#results').delegate('li li', 'mouseover', function ()
```

You just need to change your selector to only child elements.

http://jsfiddle.net/PtzF4/2/

Comment: Thanks, i didnt realize it could be so simple :)

Answer (score 0):

Two problems: That will rerun `draggable()` on the element every time you mouseover it; `delegated()` is deprecated. If all you're looking to do is have a static list of draggable elements, then just use `each()`.

```
$('#results .ui-draggable li').each(function() {
    $(this).draggable({
        revert: true,
        revertDuration: 0
    });
});
```

---

If you're looking to be able to dynamically add elements and make them draggable (which is what it looks like you want to do based on the code), look at this:
http://jsfiddle.net/PtzF4/4/ 
Removed extraneous stuff that made jsfiddle grumpy and added a logger to show the difference between my version and Selven's regarding rerunning `draggable()`.